# Converting time in SPSS from hhmm:ss to hh:mm:ss (TIME8)

Tags: date, time, spss

After a data export I get a string variable with "2017/02/22 1320:35 +000 4".

Through:

```
compute #TS = char.index(Timestamp_1, " ").
string date (A10).
compute date = char.substr(Timestamp_1,1,#TS).
alter type date (A10 = SDATE10).
```

I manage to get the date in a separate variable.

The same:

```
string time (A8).
compute time = char.substr(Timestamp_2,#TS+1,7). 
alter type time (A8 = TIME8).
```

doesn't work for the time because it is in the 'hhmm:ss' format. How do I change the string variable '1320:35' into a time variable '13:20:35'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a ":" manually into the time string by using the `concat` function before you alter the type.

```
COMPUTE time = CONCAT(CHAR.SUBSTR(time,1,2),":",(CHAR.SUBSTR(time,3))).
```

Another approach would be to extract hours, minutes and seconds from Timestamp variable individually and to use these elements inside the `TIME.HMS` function:

```
COMPUTE #hh = NUMBER(CHAR.SUBSTR(Timestamp_1,TS+1,2),F2).
COMPUTE #mm = NUMBER(CHAR.SUBSTR(Timestamp_1,TS+3,2),F2).
COMPUTE #ss = NUMBER(CHAR.SUBSTR(Timestamp_1,TS+6,2),F2).

COMPUTE time = TIME.HMS(#hh,#mm,#ss).
EXECUTE.

FORMATS time (TIME8).
```

Comment: Thank you. With this input I'm able to move forward!

Comment: Hi @Larissa if this or any (future) answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Statistics has a datetime format and, new in V24, an ISO 8601 timestamp format, YMDHMS.  If the string is converted to a regular date/time value, then the XDATE.DATE and XDATE.TIME functions can be used to extract the pieces.  The Date and Time wizard may accommodate the format you have (not sure about that +000 4 part at the end).